# Magento Price Match ( $ amount discount ) Feature on Backend for CustomerCare

Tags: magento, discount

i am working on module which help customer care to give discount to people ( called price match ) usually when your products are on different location so usually people call for price match. so if user saw product in Walmart for $150.50 and company website price is $151.50 usually user call for one $ so its very difficult for create coupon code for $1.

i know we can change the product price ( called custom price ) but after its night mare for Accounting department so our accounting department want to see discount on total order not on every product price. so i built one module.

[image]

every thing good i can apply discount to whole order with this code :

```html
$dataReturn = array();
      $postValues=$this->getRequest()->getParams();
      $quoteid=$postValues['quoteid'];
      $disocuntApply = true;
      if($disocuntApply) 
      $discountAmount =$postValues['tradeDiscountAmount'];
      $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteid);
      if($quoteid) {
      if($discountAmount>0) {
      $total=$quote->getBaseSubtotal();
      if($total < $discountAmount)
      {
         $dataReturn['error'] = true;
         $dataReturn['value'] = "Trade Discount more then order subTotal";
         $return = json_encode($dataReturn);
         echo $return;
         exit;
      }
      $quote->setSubtotal(0);
      $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);
      $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
      $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
      $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
      $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);
      $canAddItems = $quote->isVirtual()? ('billing') : ('shipping'); 
      foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {
      $address->setSubtotal(0);
      $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);
      $address->setGrandTotal(0);
      $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);
      $address->collectTotals();
      $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
      $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());
      $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
      (float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
      );
      $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
      (float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
      );
      $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
      $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());
      $quote ->save(); 
      $quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
      ->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
      ->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
      ->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
      ->save(); 
      if($address->getAddressType()==$canAddItems) {
      $address->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
      $address->setGrandTotal((float) $address->getGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
      $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
      $address->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $address->getBaseGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
      if($address->getDiscountDescription()){
      $address->setDiscountAmount(-($address->getDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
      $address->setDiscountDescription($address->getDiscountDescription().', Trade Discount');
      $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($address->getBaseDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
      }else {
      $address->setDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
      $address->setDiscountDescription('Trade Discount');
      $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
      }
      $address->save();
      }//end: if
      } //end: foreach
      //echo $quote->getGrandTotal();
      foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
       //We apply discount amount based on the ratio between the GrandTotal and the RowTotal
       $rat=$item->getPriceInclTax()/$total;
       $ratdisc=$discountAmount*$rat;
       $item->setDiscountAmount(($item->getDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty());
       $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(($item->getBaseDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty())->save();
      }
      }
      echo "true";
      }
   }
```

but when i click on submit order then i am not able to see real discount on order.

and if i enter $5 before submit i can see discount but after submit order place done but i am not able to see discount in order after place order.

so please if any one has idea msg me.

if need more details ping me.

Comment: You should check out http://www.amasty.com as they already have very reasonable priced extensions for this ( Unaffiliated )

Comment: i am checking amasty.com but i am not able to find any extension for price match..